# Как вывести изображение за границы div, используя Wordpress Visual Composer?

Tags: css, wordpress, frontend

Сразу отмечу, сайт сделан на CMS Wordpress с использованием Visual Composer. Менять это не хочу так как пользователь в дальнейшем должен обслуживать сайт.

Суть вопроса:

Есть такой блок fitness.ad-rocket.com.ua/#1514407125282-4e9c9ee0-7179 который должен выглядеть так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но у меня не получается вывести изображение за границы блока.

Для изображения пробовал ставить

Position: absolute

z-index: 999999999

И поднимать вверх, но тогда выходит вот такое:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все можно сделать и с Visual Composer. Покажите разметку html или дайте ссылку на сайт

Comment: http://fitness.ad-rocket.com.ua/#1514407125282-4e9c9ee0-7179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте `overflow: visible;` блокам:

с классом `vc_custom_1514879929781`

и `vc_tta-panel-body`

Задайте вашему img что-то вроде `transform: translateY(-50%);`

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так сейчас сделал, но есть проблема если поставить overflow: visible; классу vc_tta-panel-body
то при переключении табов один налазит на другой

Comment: Ну я тут не могу заниматься разработкой сайта. На вопрос я ответил, дал идею. Вынесите этот цветной прямоугольник выше, на уровень ряда и подвиньте с помощью postion: absolute;

Comment: Я же ничего против не имею

Comment: @VladislavChaly если ответ помог - стоит отметить его решенным.